# How to push changes in git without pull

Tags: git, github

I am new to GIT. Yesterday I made some changes to my local branch and pushed it to the local branch. Now I wanted to make some changes again and I wanted to push them again but I was always being asked to pull. What if I dont want to pull? I want to push my new local changes without pulling. I did a PULL yesterday but it somehow merged my files and they became corrupt since duplicated pieces of code was added by git to solve the merge conflict. Can somebody help me with the process? How to start and handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your repository updated with the remote branches especially `master`. You can simply do it by, running the below commands

```
git checkout master // If you are not in the master
git pull origin master
```

Now switch to your local branch and update it with the `master`. But before that make sure all the local changes are committed.

```
git checkout <branch_name>
git rebase master
git push origin <branch_name>:<branch_name>
```

In the current scenario, you have to force push your changes to remote.

```
git push origin <branch_name> --force
git push origin <branch_name> -f
```

Note: Both the commands do the same thing, it just that second is shorter than the first one.

Comment: Just a very noobie question to ask. For every little change do I have to add, commit and push? Is there a way we could sync changes directly to my local remote branch?

Comment: You should only push the meaningful changes to the remote. But yes, you should add and commit into the local branch. Also, just before pushing the changes to the remote you may do `squash` so that many small commits can be merged into one.

Answer (score 0):

Always Pull Before a Push

> This is a bedrock rule. Before you try to push code out to the
> repository, you should always pull all the current changes from the
> remote repository to your local machine. Doing so will ensure that
> your local copy is in sync with the remote repository. Remember, other
> people have been pushing to the remote copy, and if you push before
> syncing up, you could end up with multiple heads or merge conflicts
> when you push. By default, Git will not allow you to push changes onto
> a branch that has remote commits. You can turn this feature off, but
> it’s not recommended.

Pull frequently

> On large teams, the central repository will continuously be changing.
> You should endeavor to keep your local machine as close to the remote
> repository as possible. The way to do that is to pull all the changes
> on the remote server to your local copy. You can do this as often as
> you like, and should do it frequently — at least once a day if not
> more.

Comment: What if I want to scrap all the changes I pushed and push new changes again?

Comment: @MananRekhi If you want to scrap local changes have not pushed, you can use ```git rebase``` to ```drop``` that commit, but that also will leading to some conflicts.If you just want to combine multiple commits into 1,you can use ```git rebase```with ```squash```,and the ```force``` push to git

Answer (score 0):

This is because your remote repository on Github (what big professional programmers call 'origin') **is not automatically tracking your local git repository when you first create it.**

Whenever you create a GitHub, ALWAYS run

```
git pull origin master
```

This takes the code from Github (usually a `README.MD` or any small file you made, no one usually writes source code in Github itself) by 'fetching' them from Github into your local repository (your computer) and then 'merges' (unites) the two repositories.

You might see online
`git pull origin` and ask yourself why 'master' is needed at the end of the command. This is because most developers with many, many, branches of their project need to specify which BRANCH they're pulling from. In your case, it's just you, so you don't really need it, but just use master anyways, unless you have some compelling reason not to.

If you're still confused, [use this for reference](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-pull-explained/).